# Convert String to word and send it ti textView

Tags: android, textview

```
public void beginListenForData() {

     Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          int readBufferPosition = 0;
          byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
          boolean stopWorker = false;
          Handler handler = new Handler(); 
         
          public void run() {

               while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                  
                   try {      
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();            
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++) {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];                                        
                                
                              readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                              byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                              System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                              data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                              readBufferPosition = 0;
                          
                              handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                   public void run() {
                                    
                                       System.out.println(data);
                                       getData.setTextView(data);//not working

                                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   }
                                   
                              });                                    
                        }
                   }
              }catch (IOException ex) {
                   stopWorker = true;
                   break;
              }
                 
                   catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                  
         }
    }
         
});
```

So i am getting a good letters that LogCat shows me:

- 04-13 23:36:57.202: I/System.out(25711): J
- 04-13 23:36:57.212: I/System.out(25711): O
- 04-13 23:36:57.702: I/System.out(25711): N
- 04-13 23:36:58.202: I/System.out(25711): A
- 04-13 23:36:58.712: I/System.out(25711): S

  how to i get theese letters into one word: JONAS and show it on a textView?

Comment: What does getData.setTextView(data); make?

Comment: May I ask what the program does and your end goal?  There is an awful lot of copying data to send data to a TextView.  PacketBytes -> ReadBuffer -> encodedBytes -> String Data -> TextView.  Not to mention a sleep which will slow things down horribly, but I hope that is there for debugging reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

First, make a class variable, so

```
private String text;
```

Then, inside run, make data add on to text each time, so

```
public void run() {
    text += data;
```

This will add on to the overall string. Then, finally, to make the TextView display this information, first you need to get your textView.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id./*id of your textview*/);
tv.setText(text);
```

That should all go inside your run method.

Comment if you have any questions about how this works.

Comment: OK, but where correctly put 'tv.setText(text);', that it will show me 'text'
cause now i get null pointer exeption, but in LOGCat i van see JONAS

Comment: Did you try running it in debugging mode? If it can print out text, it shouldn't be null